# Uncommitted new row cannot be deleted in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, c#-3.0

I have Gridview in WinForms, I want to remove last empty row in GridView I try to use below code but it show me error

My Code:

```
bool Empty = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Empty = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() != "")
            {
                Empty = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (Empty)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        }
```

Showing Error:

> Uncommitted new row cannot be deleted.

Comment: Nested for loops is not a good idea ... It is easier way to this, just remove the nulls and "" from the source and rebind the Grid ! Work with the DataSource !

Comment: Isn't this something the data grid does automatically? Are you interfering with that somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You try to delete a row while still you iterate through rows. Which means, after some point, i will exceed the count of rows. It could be the reason...

Try to put them in a list and then iterate through that list. You can only delete then...

For example :

```
     List<int> toBeDeleted = new List<int>();


     // always follow conventions...
     bool empty = false;


      // dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1 due to AllowUserToAddRows = True
      for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
        {
            empty = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() != "")
                {
                    empty = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (empty)
            {
                toBeDeleted.Add(i);
            }
        }

      foreach(var f in toBeDeleted)
     {
         dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(f);
       }
```

Comment: I want to delete empty row in dataGridView, Can you please make a code for me?

Comment: What is Empty on above code? It show me error "'System.Empty' is inaccessible due to its protection level" and "'System.Empty' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'"

Comment: Oops. Sorry. You can add it like bool empty = true; Don't use it with the big initial like bool Empty = true.

Comment: same error Uncommitted new row cannot be deleted. :(

Comment: can you post some examples of your grid ?

Comment: Grid Have 5 column 4 are simple text 1 is dropdown, dropdown have some data which are come from database. when I insert data in Grid, automatically new row generated. so I want to remove that row if empty. Hope I clear my question.

Comment: Heh ! It throws this error because a your gridview has AllowUsersToAddRows property set to True. Which adds a new empty row on the display. So when you iterate through dataGridView1.Rows.Count, it also counts the new row. So all you have to do is to iterate through minus one.    dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1 and that's it.

Comment: I put minus one, dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1, now code not working. nothing happened when run the code :(

Comment: Can you extend your above code little bit ? Show us your datasource and when and where are you binding it to the GridView ? Sorry for the extended comments everyone !